# Unity IoC: Where to place the assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a few Assemblies: MyInterfaces.dll, MyImplementations.dll, MyTestApp.exe

In my config I do the mapping but I get the following error during runtime:

The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

My question is:

Do I need to register my two assembly in the GAC or do just the /bin folder of MyTestApp?  Otherwise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the config your describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assemblies should just have to be accessible to your app through any of the "normal" means (in the GAC, in the same directory, etc).

Are you using fully-qualified assembly names in your config? Like:

> MyInterfaces, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

You could try using the [Fusion Logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to see what is happening too.

Comment: a minute after I posted the question I got it fixed.  I didnt have to do full-qualified name with token and culture... I just had to do this and make sure the assemblies are in the bin folder:

Comment: <type type ="MyComp.AbstractInterfaces.ILogger,MyComp.AbstractInterfaces" mapTo="MyComp.Loggers.FileLogger, MyComp.Loggers" name="FileLogger"></type>